# linux/ubuntu/stat() works differently when using string literal and string variable

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-18.04, string-literals, stat

i want to print the file size of current directory.
so i used stat() function with path and stat struct.
current directory is /home/minky/project/project2. the file that i want to print file size is in project2.
when i used string variable. it return error which is "no such file or directory".
however, when is using string literal, it works correctly(i mean, program prints size of the file.
i want to *make program that when i input filename(standard input) then program prints size of that file.*
but it works diffrently when using string variable and string literal....
is there any mistake in my code?(program is so long that i skipped unrelated code)

```
void do_size(char * command){//ignore this command... this is for another part 


    char * filename;//filename that  i want to print file size.
    struct stat  statbuf;

    char * rPath = calloc(BUF_LEN, sizeof(char));
    char * realPath = calloc(BUF_LEN, sizeof(char));

    filename = token_command[1];//token_command[1] is from another function. 

    //make relative path
    sprintf(rPath, "./%s", filename);

    //make absolute path  
    realpath(rPath, realPath);

    if(stat(realPath, &statbuf) < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "stat error\n");
            printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("%ld %s\n", statbuf.st_size, rPath);




}
```

---

but i change program(string variable to string literal) like this,

```
if(stat("/home/minky/project/project2", &statbuf) < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "stat error\n");
            printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
```

it works exactly and returns no error("no such file or directory").

Comment: How do you know the string in `filename` is correct? Did you look at it with a debugger? Or did you just print it out? If you're checking by eye, how do you know there's not a whitespace character at the end? (Debuggers are great tools. Learn to use one now: it will save you lots of time later.)

Comment: Put `printf("<%s>", realPath);` right before the line containing `stat` and tell us what is displayed. I'm sure it's not `</home/minky/project/project2>`

Comment: ... and what is `realPath`? And BTW having two identifiers `realPath` and `realpath` which are almost the same, is not a good ideas as it makes your code less readable.